# How to get parameter value of enum in IF condition?

Tags: swift, if-statement, enums

How do write this

```
switch parameter {
case .CaseA(let valueA):
   print(valueA)
}
```

as an If condition statement? This doesn't work:

```
if parameter == .CaseA(let valueA) {
   print(valueA)
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `if case` as follows

```
enum Foo {
    case A(Int)
    case B(String)
}

let parameter = Foo.A(42)

/* if case ... */
if case .A(let valueA) = parameter {
    print(valueA) // 42
}
```

The `if case` pattern matching is equivalent to a `switch` pattern matching with an empty (non-used) default case, e.g.

```
/* switch ... */
switch parameter {
case .A(let valueA):
    print(valueA) // 42
case _: ()
}
```

For details, see [the Language Reference - Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html).

Comment: Thanks. Did you mean `if case .A(let valueA) == parameter {`?

Comment: @Manuel Actually, no. We're performing enumeration pattern matching rather than checking for equality; where operator `=` is used for the former, in this context.

Comment: Got it, now I'm even more impressed. Thanks

Comment: @Manuel Happy to help. (All assignments `=` can actually be seen as pattern matching followed by---given match success---bounding/assigning of the matched value; see the supplied link in my answer for details).

Comment: `case _:` is equivalent to an `else` clause. So, in your example, the closer `switch` analogue would be `default: break`.

Comment: @milos `case _` pattern matches to anything, and as you write this could be seen as an `else` clause to the `switch` control structure. Afaik, there is, however, no difference between a single `case _` clause or a `default` clause: they both provide exhaustive coverage in case none of the other cases catches. I agree, however, that using `break` rather that nothing (`()`) would be a slightly better anology for comparison with the single `if case` clause (even if `break` vs nothing at the end of a switch structure is in essence the same; no remaining logic to short-circuit by the `break`).